# Toon Shader + Textures, how could i do?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, toon-shading

I'm using a Classic Toon Shader, but I dont know how I could combine a texture with that shader

[image: my model wiouth the texture]

Now if I put the *Fac* of the mix node to $0,5$ this happens

[image]

How could I combine the two without losing any detail?

These are the nodes I use

[image: Nodes I use]

Comment: What does the texture look like? What do you mean by "details"? I guess you don't want that the model gets a darker tone? I don't know what it should look like but I would try a mask for the *Fac* instead of the plain 0.5 value.